# I want to save it as a reference

Tags: feature-request, printing

There are some questions where both the question and answer are excellent.  This is unsurprising, there are some excellent folks on cross-validated.

I have a "library" where I store excellent and useful articles.  I use it for bibliography, and when I have to "dust off" a subject it is my first stop.

I wish there was a convenient way to make the question and answer into a pdf with a decently formatted bibliographic reference as a header.

Can you suggest something less klugy than "print to file" and manual annotation.  Do we have a "save" button somewhere?

Comment: This is a good question, but did you notice [How to print a Cross Validated question or answer?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/2180/7290) How does your Q differ from that?

Comment: that answers it.  I can delete this question, if appropriate.